# gelocation - asynchronous callback not working with error - Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, geolocation, asynccallback

myFn.getMyCurrentPosition(data, function(data){ //Async call, need to use data like a callback - this section doesnt work. How can I use the current position coords and use it in a different function like a successfull callback?

```
var myFn = {
    this.localVar : null, 
    mysuccess : function (position) {
        this.myLocalVar = position.coords.latitude + ','+ position.coords.longitude; 
        return this.myLocalVar; 
    }, 
    myerror : function (error) {     
        return null; 
    }, 
    getMyCurrentPosition : function() {
        if(navigator && navigator.geolocation) { 
            //WORKS - mysuccess sets data asyncrhonously. 
            return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.mysuccess, this.myerror);          
        }
    }, 
    myInitializer : function(){
        //Initialize map, marker etc. for google maps API
        myFn.getMyCurrentPosition( function(){ //Async call, need to use data like a callback 
            //This code never runs! 
            if(this.myLocalVar){
                //doSomethingAfterCall - using this.myLocalVar, map, etc.;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Update: TRIED THIS:

```
var myFn = {
    mysuccess: function (position) {
        myFn.myInitializer(); 
    }, 
    myerror: function (error) { 
        myFn.myInitializer(); 
    }, 

     myInitializer : function(){
        //Initialize map, marker etc. for google maps API
    }, 
    onLoadSet : function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.mysuccess, this.myerror);
    }

} 

myFn.onLoadSet();
```

Get this error: Failed to execute 'getCurrentPosition' on 'Geolocation': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.

Comment: `getMyCurrentPosition` doesn't take any parameters... so.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `myFn.getMyCurrentPosition`, you pass it two arguments (`data` and a function).

When you defined it:

> ```
> function() {
> ```

You didn't tell it to accept any arguments (and you didn't use the `arguments` object either).

You need to actually use the arguments you pass to it if you want anything to be done with them.

Comment: Thank you for helping. actually I dont need to pass anything, just use the returned position coordinates. I also have some local variables where the call getMyCurrentPosition is made, so I want to use them and the position coordinates. Is there a way to do that. So basically, I need only a callback after the position/data is set, i.e get the data returned, without passing anything.?

Comment: var map =something; myFn.getMyCurrentPosition( function(data){ //data needs to be the position - lat/long...  });

Comment: There are no returned coordinates. It's an async function. You can't return from an async function. That's why we pass callbacks.

Comment: can you show me how to pass/use the callback, that is the section I'm struggling to work with. I have a bunch of functionality after I get the position, but it needs to run only if position is returned successfully.

Comment: so in the sucess callback, I have to move whatever it is I'm trying to do on sucess? I can't really write it out the way I have? let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the new [Permission api](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/)
I have built a extended version/polyfill of it with support for requesting & querying the state of the geolocation all promisify: [browser-su](https://github.com/jimmywarting/browser-su)

```
/***************
 *    query    *
 ***************/
su.query({
    name: 'geolocation'
}).then(permission => {
    console.log(permission) // {state, onchange}
    console.log(permission.state) // granted, prompt or denied
})


/***************
 *   request   *
 ***************/
su.request({
    name: 'geolocation',
    timeout: 5000 // Optional
}).then(position => {
    console.log(position)
} err => {
    console.log(err.name, err.message)
    // RequestDeniedError       User blocked access to geolocation
    // RequestDismissedError    User dismissed access to geolocation
    // RequestTimeoutError      Timeout expired
    // RequestUnavailableError  Position is unavailable
    // RequestUnsupportedError  This client dose not seem to have geolocation support
})
```

Firefox will also soon have support for revoking permission

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. I tried the other approach but probably messed up something in my syntax. It was a couple of issues: 
The JS needs to reference variable myFn.method instead of this.method for the myInitializer call within success/error callbacks. Because locationSuccess/error are expected callbacks, this.locationSucess works in the callback for getcurrentPosition.

```
var myFn = {
    locationSuccess: function (position) {
        myFn.myInitializer(position.coords); 
    }, 
    locationError: function (error) {  
        myFn.myInitializer();  
    }, 

     myInitializer : function(data){
        //Initialize map, marker etc. for google maps API
       //if(data) { doSomething(); }
       //else { doSomethingElse(); }

    }, 
    onLoadSet : function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.locationSucess, this.locationError, {timeout:1000});
    }

};

myFn.onLoadSet();
```

Another issue is known: Add a timeout as third parameter for the

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.locationSuccess, this.locationError, {**timeout:1000**});
```